# How helpful is $f^{-1}(z)=\frac1{2\pi i}\oint\ln(1-\frac z{f(w)})dw$, or the method to find it, in deriving integral representations of $f^{-1}(z)$?

Tags: integration, contour-integration, inverse-function, z-transform, lagrange-inversion

$\DeclareMathOperator \erf{erf}$
Wolfram Alpha gives the following [$\erf^{-1}(z)$ series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=series+expansion+inverf%28x%29):

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{2\pi n}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{it}\erf(e^{it})^{-n}dt$$

which can be derived via [Lagrange inversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) and [the inverse Z transform](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Inverse_Z-transform). $\erf$ is the [error function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html):

$$\erf^{-1}(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{da^{n-1}}\left(\frac a{\erf(a)}\right)^n\right|_0$$

Combining it with $$\left.\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)\right|_0=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1}f(z)z^{-n-1}dz$$

gives the blockquoted series. Additionally, we can evaluate the sum to get:
$$
\begin{split}
\erf^{-1}(z) &=-\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{|w|=1}\ln\left(1-\frac z{\erf(w)}\right)dw\\
&=-\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{it}\ln\left(1-\frac z{\erf(e^{it})}\right)dt
\end{split}
$$
[shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7Binverf%280.3%29%2C-NIntegrate%5B%28e%5E%28i+t%29+log%281+-+0.3%2F%28erf%28e%5E%28i+t%29%29%29%29%29%2F%282+%CF%80%29%2C%7Bt%2C-%CF%80%2C%CF%80%7D%5D%7D). Although it likely can be generalized, this method works for $f(z)$ monotonic near $z=0,f(0)=0$, and $f’(0)\ne0$. One concern with the method is that we find the formula:
$$
\begin{split}
g(f^{-1}(z)) &= g(0)-\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{|w|=1}g’(w)\ln\left(1-\frac z{f(w)}\right)dw\\
&=g(0)-\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{it}g’(e^{it})\ln\left(1-\frac z{f(e^{it})}\right)dt
\end{split}
$$
which seems like a tautology because the formula applies to many arbitrary $f(z)$ without seemingly simplifying. Additionally, the formula is reminiscent to the one derivable from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2320568/905886), a version of the [Cauchy integral formula for $f^{-1}(z)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2821606/variant-of-cauchys-integral-formula-for-the-inverse-function):

> $$
> \begin{split}
> f^{-1}(z) &=\frac1{2\pi i}\oint\frac{wf’(w)}{f(w)-z}dz\\ 
> & =\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{2it}f’(e^{it})}{f(e^{it})-z}dt\\
> & =1-\frac1{2\pi i}\oint\ln(f(w)-z)dw\\
> & =1-\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{it}\ln(f(e^{it})-z)dt
> \end{split}
> $$

saying

> But no formula of this type would be worth publishing in the 20th or 21st centuries

which implies the $g(f^{-1}(z))$ formula may not be as useful due to its similarity to the Cauchy integral formula.

How helpful is this $g(f^{-1}(z))$ formula/Lagrange-inversion-inverse-Z-transform method in deriving integral representations of $f^{-1}(z)$?